# My Solution is not building via Gated Check-in in Team Foundation Server 2013 but building fine in local machine Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, portable-class-library, win-universal-app

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013.

I am facing an issue while building my solution on the TFS Build server.

My project builds successfully in my local machine with all platforms(x86, x64 and ARM), but it is failing in the Tfs Build for the platforms x64 and ARM with the following error

```
App.xaml.cs (2): The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTasks' does not exist in the namespace MyApp (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My project is a Windows Universal App with a portable class Library for background tasks which has been referenced both in the Windows and Windows Phone projects. This portable class library generates a winmd(not a dll) and in the configuration manager in my Visual Studio only Any CPU is supported for this project.

I installed Visual Studio 2013 in the Build Server and got the latest sources and was able to build the solution in all platforms successfully. But the build agent running on the same machine is throwing the build error as mentioned earlier.
I also tried to build the failed Build Definition Source. It successfully builds in VS2013.

I believe it should be some configuration change in TFS Server/Build Server.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Resolved it by changing the "MSBuild Platform" parameter to "x86".

Comment: I tried that but with no luck.
My project still fails for x64 and ARM.
The build error that I get(only in TFS Gated-Checkin Build) in x64 and ARM is the following
"The type or namespace name 'BackgroundTasks' does not exist in the namespace 'MyApp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"